# Delete action and create action for Rails version 2.3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Just now I am starting to study Ruby on Rails.

```
ruby version=1.8.7
rails version =2.3.2
```

I created delete and create new user action but present some errors, 
the errors are:

```
    uninitialized constant User::Id
    Extracted source (around line #19):

 16:         <td><%= user.fname %></td>
 17:         <td><%= user.lname %></td>
 18:         <td><%= user.dob %></td>
 19:         <td><%= button_to "delete", :url => {:controller => :users,:action => 'destroy',:id =>user.id}, :method => :delete %></td>
 20:       </tr>
 21:     <% end %>
 22: </table>
```

My MySQL database table is:

```
id  fname  lname   dob
 1  kamal   vimal  2012.02.12
 2  rahu    sharmi 2012.05.26
 3  mithun  kavi   2012.03.07
```

Class user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

set_primary_key :id
has_one :id
end
```

My controller is:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def index
@users=User.all
end

def destroy
    # User.primary_key='id'
    @users=User.find(:id)
    @users.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "You have successfully Delete Recode"
end

def new
    @users=User.new
end

 def create
    @users=User.new(params[:users])
    if @user.save
        redirect_to_users_path
        flash[:notice] = "Your record is created!"
    else
        render :action => "index"
    end
 end
end
```

My view is:

```
 <% @users.each do |user| %>

 <%= button_to "delete", :url => {:controller => :users,:action => 'destroy',:id =>user.id}, :method => :delete %>
 <% end %>
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Unrelated, but why learn with such an old version of either?

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of misunderstanding.

### Users Controller

If you look the delete method in the controller

```
def destroy
  @users=User.find(:id)
  [...]
```

You are passing a **symbol** to the [find](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.2/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class) function instead of the id from the **delete** request. You can get the id by using **params[:id]**, as you have done with the create function.

```
def destroy
  @users=User.find(params[:id])
  [...]
```

The following are only suggestions.

I will also change the instance variable name from **@users** to **@user** here and in the new and the create method, since you are getting/build a single user.

If your routes.rb is set like

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :users
end
```

you don't need to specify the url specifying the controller and the action in the **button_to** helper, but you can use the **path helpers**

```
button_to "delete", user_path(user), :method => :delete
```

### User model

You can remove both the statements.

You should user **set_primary_key** only if the primary key in the table differs from the default 'id'.

The association is misused.

With the [has_one](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.2/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one) method you are telling Rails the **User model** is related with the **model 'id'** through a **1:1 relation** which, I suppose, is not what you want.

### Final Thoughts

Read carefully the [Ruby on Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/) if you did not, it's a good starting point.

In addition, you are using a **really** old version of Rails and Ruby, which are not supported anymore. If there aren't any specific reason, like working on a legacy project, I suggest you to study a more recent version like Rails 4 on ruby 2.2.

Comment: thank you now is working but change one code button_to "delete", user_path(user.id), :method => :delete

Comment: Usually the path helper should do that for you. It can be the symptom of some other issue. If the answer worked for you, mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer .